# ColdFusion CFDump Web service

Tags: web-services, coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I'm in the process of migrating our web applications from a Cold Fusion 9 server to a Cold Fusion 2016 server and one of the web service calls that works perfectly in CF9 is now raising the following error in CF2016.

> Web service operation InsertBank with parameters
>   {2,JOHNSON,BRIAN,450,450100530,21/02/2017,C,11212,006,128661543321,A,en}
>   cannot be found.

I'm calling the method directly through CFScript *(I've already defined the web service using `createObject()`, and assigned it to an application variable for easy use)*

```
result = Application.AdminWS.InsertBank(Trim(Application.ApplicationId),Trim(uname),Trim(Session.Employee.Client.xmlText),Trim(Session.Employee.Certificate.xmlText),Trim(DateFormat(Now(),"dd/mm/yyyy")),"C",Trim(instiNum),Trim(accouNum),Trim(transNum),Trim(varAccStatus),session.language);
```

I'm aware that Axis2 was introduced in CF10 however in ColdFusion Administrator I set the default as Axis1; I don't believe this is the cause of the issue. I've tried refreshing the WSDL however the only difference between the WSDL files between the two servers are the URLs.

Is there a way to `cfdump` a web service and view all of it's parameters?

Comment: Dump the web service object (probably `Application.AdminWS`) and take a look at the signature of that method to view what arguments it is expecting, ie InsertBank().

Comment: Odds are, you'll have to do some refactoring. We just finished the extensive process of moving from CF 9 to 2016 ourselves and there were a number of things that CF 9 "let slip through" that 2016 will not.

Comment: @Leigh Wow, I'm not sure why I didn't try that from the get-go. Thanks!

Comment: @AdrianJ.Moreno You're exactly right, the issue was that my web service expects an additional parameter that CF9 quite simply ignored.